# Error when use do_upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have a problem when I use do_upload its always returns an error saying 'The upload path does not appear to be valid'.

```
function save_blog(){
    $config['upload_path'] = 'ftp://username:password@hostname:port/public_html/img/blog/';
    //$config['upload_path'] = 'img/blog/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

    get_instance()->load->library('upload', $this->config);
    echo $config['upload_path'];
    if($this->upload->do_upload('myDoc'))
    {
        echo "file upload success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
}
```

On my server there are path /public_html/img/blog/

PS* i can use do_upload when i used a simple code like http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

but on my project I have to upload 2 files in one click so I try to use `$this->upload->do_upload('myDoc')` for one of my input first but it still error.

Comment: Shouldn't the `$this->config` be `$this->config['upload_path']` ?

Comment: post your error message

Comment: The upload path does not appear to be valid'.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated:

If you need to upload files, do **do_upload** first by your first method to local folder, and then **FTP upload** the local file to FTP server.

I think if you need to upload via **FTP**. for establishing a valid connection to FTP.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/ftp.html

**Example for Codeigniter.**

```
$this->load->library('ftp');

$config['hostname'] = 'ftp.example.com';
$config['username'] = 'your-username';
$config['password'] = 'your-password';
$config['debug']    = TRUE;

$this->ftp->connect($config);

$this->ftp->upload('/local/path/to/myfile.html', '/public_html/myfile.html', 'ascii', 0775);

$this->ftp->close();
```

**Exmaple for PHP only.** (Credits to http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/ftp-example.htm)

```
// FTP access parameters
$host = 'ftp.example.org';
$usr = 'example_user';
$pwd = 'example_password';

// file to move:
$local_file = './example.txt';
$ftp_path = '/data/example.txt';

// connect to FTP server (port 21)
$conn_id = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die ("Cannot connect to host");

// send access parameters
ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd) or die("Cannot login");

// turn on passive mode transfers (some servers need this)
// ftp_pasv ($conn_id, true);

// perform file upload
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $local_file, FTP_ASCII);

// check upload status:
print (!$upload) ? 'Cannot upload' : 'Upload complete';
print "\n";

/*
** Chmod the file (just as example)
*/

// If you are using PHP4 then you need to use this code:
// (because the "ftp_chmod" command is just available in PHP5+)
if (!function_exists('ftp_chmod')) {
   function ftp_chmod($ftp_stream, $mode, $filename){
        return ftp_site($ftp_stream, sprintf('CHMOD %o %s', $mode, $filename));
   }
}

// try to chmod the new file to 666 (writeable)
if (ftp_chmod($conn_id, 0666, $ftp_path) !== false) {
    print $ftp_path . " chmoded successfully to 666\n";
} else {
    print "could not chmod $file\n";
}

// close the FTP stream
ftp_close($conn_id);
```